# Empty set representation

Tags: python

Could someone explain the following?

```
>>> a = {1}
>>> b = {2}
>>> a & b == set()
True
>>> a & b == {}
False
```

Why is this choice made?

Comment: @skyl Set literals were added ~2.7 I believe. Edit: Yup, it's [a 3.1 feature backported into 2.7](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features) as it's a non-breaking change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code `a & b == {}` is comparing a ANDed with b with `{}`, an empty dictionary. So, the result of the and and an empty dictionary are different and the result is false.

Comment: +1 @DimitrisLeventeas for sheer comedic value

Comment: Interestingly, `{i for i in range(5)}` returns a set

Comment: `a or b` gives `set([1])` whereas `a | b` gives `set([1,2])`. What do the operators mean then?

Comment: @AbhranilDas see [this](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) - `|` is the same as `union`, `or` does the same as always, returning the first element which evaluates to `True`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget If you want a dict comprehension, put a `key: value` pair there instead. E.g: `{i: i+1 for i in range(5)}` will produce a dict.